# the root access of Gerrit2 user was removed recently, post which gitweb option is not working. Is it mandatory to have root access for gerrit user?

Tags: linux, git, amazon-web-services, gerrit

Earlier, I had root user access on the Linux server, where Gerrit code review and GIT is installed. most gerrit files like gerrit.sh is owned by gerrit2 user and root access of that also has been revoked.

Recently I am not able to access GITWEB from gerrit UI and i noticed that gerrit.sh is failing to start. So does it have anything to do with root access?

Comment: did you check service logs?

Comment: Restart Gerrit and look at the GERRIT_SITE/logs/error_log file. Add the relevant errors to your question.

Comment: That's an important issue here, that nothing is getting recorded in the error_log file for the click which is not working in UI.

Comment: I am getting below error:

'[2018-06-13 03:38:25,529] ERROR com.google.gerrit.pgm.Daemon : Unable to start daemon
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot bind to NewVoE-GIT01:29418
      Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
.
.
.
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)'